# Multiple barplots using 3 columns of a df

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I am rather new to R and this is my first of hopefully many posts in this forum. I got a problem which i hope you can help me with.

I have a dataframe with around 15 columns (characters and integers) P1, P2, P3, .. P15. Around 5000 rows.

I want to produce several barplots:

1. for every P1 (Int) 1 Plot
2. for every P2 1 bar in the corresponding P1, stacked by
3. P3 (character) -> rows have to be count

Right now (like 8 hours of work) i am here:

```
dta_plot <- dta %>% select(Visit, City, DogSpecies) # Visit is P1 , City is P2 and DogSpecies is P3

ggplot(dta_plot, aes(x = as.factor(Visitg), fill = City)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "count")
```

But that obv. leaves out Species.

R is a hell of a program i guess :)

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(head(dta_plot, 20))`.

Comment: If you want a seperate plot for every species, maybe ````+ facet_grid(~DogSpecies)````would give you what you want?

Comment: @EmLaskey: Thats exactly what i was looking for, thank you

Comment: @ Rui Barradas - thanks for your effort - i cant post sample data since they are somewhat sensible.

Comment: @yayacmtex, tip for you future questions, if your datas are sensible you can use the free open R dataset (like `iris` or `mtcars`) to reproduce your problem without any privacy problem.

Comment: Thank you, will do that.